# Check box not called by jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have the following web page which has the check box and textbox

```
 `<asp:CheckBox ID="ChkCcList" runat="server" Text="Email CC list"    />        
                     </td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail"  TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" MaxLength="200" Height="70px" Width="201px"  Enabled = "false"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail"
 ErrorMessage="<br />Please enter valid emails." ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*([;]\s*\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<br /><br /></td>
</tr>`
```

Jquery code:

```
$('#ChkCcList').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        this.checked = confirm("Are you sure?");       
    }
});
```

`

can you please tell me why this is not called when the checkbox is clicked

Comment: Please provide the rendered HTML instead of your server-side code.

Comment: This isn't classic asp, I've retagged it as asp.net

Answer (score 2):

You have an asp.net control so you cannot just use the Id. You would need to look at ChkCcList.ClientID to get the id that is given to the rendered client control on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The click event handler needs to be registered in the `$(document).ready`
I.e;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ChkCcList').click(function() { if (!$(this).is(':checked')) { 
        this.checked = confirm("Are you sure?");
    } });
}
```